# Vue.js + Express: Cannot get .prevent / e.preventDefault() to work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js, preventdefault

I've been trying to mash Vue.js and Express together, to use for small apps.

I'm currently tearing my hair out trying to get the client to send data to the server via a form, without refreshing the page. Obviously, I look to e.preventDefault()

Vue.js, according to the documentation [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers) allows you to do this using an event modifier, which I've tried:

```
form(id="myForm", method="POST", action="/", v-on:submit.prevent="submitForm")
```

*(I'm also using Jade/Pug as my template engine)*

As you can see, I'm using the prevent modifier in the exact same way as in the documentation, and the method "submitForm" IS being called, it is just not preventing the refresh.

I went a bit deeper and tried the old school vue.js method, which is passing the event argument directly into the submitForm method, to try directly hit it with preventDefault()

```
submitForm: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
      console.log("Called!");
}
```

But this still doesn't stop the page reloading. Any help or tips?

Comment: Alright, seems to be something to do with `document.getElementById("myForm").submit();`

Comment: So why do you call `submit()` if you don't want to submit it? Instead you should use AJAX to send whatever you need to server. In submitForm function you're saying do not submit and then submit,WHY? It doesn't even make sense.

Comment: Yeah, figured that out. I'm still learning a lot about Javascript, and interpreted what submit() did wrong having read posts trying to solve my issue in the beginning. You have a very poor tone - what makes sense to you may not make sense to others. After all, I was trying to submit the data to the server so calling something called "submit" wasn't really something I felt was wrong. Thank you anyway, you definitely would have lead me in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry for the *poor tone* :)

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById("myForm").submit();`
This was the cause. It's not just going to submit the data, it's going to do everything a submit button would do.

Look into AJAX if you're in my position.